# Ember setupController hook in route disconnects model from template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to set a controller property as soon as my login route is entered. At the moment, I am using **method 1**, which relies on **init** in the controller. It works fine, but my understanding is that it is better to use a setupController hook in the route. Ember data shows the record which has been created and the email and password fields update when you type.

I have tried to change the code, to use a setupController hook in the route **(Method 2)**, rather that relying on init in the controller. With this method, the new record is created when entering the route, but email and password are undefined in Ember data, and don't update when typing.

Is there a way that I can still use setupController without disconnecting the model?

**Method 1 - Working**

routes/login.js

```js
model: function() {
  return this.store.createRecord('authorisation');
},
```

controllers/login.js

```js
setPreLoginMessage: function() {
  this.set('preLoginMessage', 'Please enter your username and password.'));
}.on('init'),
```

templates/login.hbs

```html
{{input placeholder="Email" value=model.email}} 
{{input placeholder="Password" value=model.password}}
```

**Method 2 - Not working**

routes/login.js

```js
model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('authorisation');
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('preLoginMessage', 'Enter your username and password'));
},
```

templates/login.hbs

```html
{{input placeholder="Email" value=model.email}} 
{{input placeholder="Password" value=model.password}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding the default `setupController` functionality which is:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
}
```

So you either just use this line in your `setupController` as well, or, which is better, just call `super.setupController(...arguments);` which will run the code from your base class:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  super.setupController(...arguments);
  controller.set('preLoginMessage', 'Enter your username and password'));
}
```

Generally you should *always* consider to call `super.<method name>()` when you override functions.

Comment: Thank you- I added the line **this._super(controller, model);** and it works great.